# golang: github/gorilla/mux supports regression url path

Tags: go, http, path, gorilla

When I want url path works well, with tail "/", and without tail "/"

```
mux1      *mux.Router

mux1.Handle("/example/", ...).Methods("GET")
```

I want these 2 urls works both :  https://host/api/example/ and https://host/api/example

But

```
mux1.Handle("/example/?", ...).Methods("GET")
```

not work.

Comment: use `PathPrefix`, i will write a demo if you need

Answer (score 2):

When you define a route in Go using `mux.Handle`, the path you specify is an exact match. This means that `/example/` and `/example` are different paths, and you need to define a route for both of them separately.

One way to achieve this is to use the `mux.PathPrefix` method to match all paths that start with `/example` and then use `mux.StripPrefix` to remove the /example prefix from the URL before passing it to your handler. Here's an example:

```golang
mux := mux.NewRouter()
mux.PathPrefix("/example").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/example", myHandler))

// ...

http.ListenAndServe(":8080", mux)
```